# Facebook4j Json Object to pojo

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook4j FQL query i want to convert my query result to my own object.I tried to convert but it does not convert jsonObject to own pojo  my code is

```
String query = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()";
JSONArray jsonArray = facebook.executeFQL(query);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("uid2"));
}
```

I want to convert jsonObject to my own pojo userDetails

Comment: Consider using another JSON library then: Jackson for instance, or Gson. They have far better deserialization capabilities than org.json.

Comment: From Gson how do i achive it has gson.fromJson(responseBody, some.class); only how i convert json object to pojo

Comment: Just make sure fields in your JSON and POJO have the same name and structure, then call fromJSON(json, yourpojo.class). That's all.